# How to use embedded image inside Toast

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

For few days I'm strugling with following problem:

Let's say I have my toast form in xml in my desktop app:

```xml
<toast>
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastImageAndText04">
      <image id="1" src=""/>
      <text id="2">Line 1</text>
      <text id="3">Line 2</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</toast>
```

and I'd like to display inside this toast some image embedded inside the app (I want to be able to deliver it in one package together with app).

How can I do that?

I've tried using CallingAssembly, however it gives me file stream, not the path. I also tried to convert my image to base64 but it raised exception due to "too big toast content". Any clues?

Edit: Adding my toast method + example call:

```
public void Toast(string message, string toastTemplatePath)
{
    var callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    System.IO.Stream file = callingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(toastTemplatePath);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
    XmlDocument toastXml = new XmlDocument();
    toastXml.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
    var text = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0];
    text.AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));
    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("App.ProjectName").Show(toast);
}
```

Example call:

```
_toaster.Toast("Message", "ProjectName.Toaster.Xml.ToastNewDriveDetected.xml");
```

Comment: If you use `<image id="1" src="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"/>` to display the StoreLogo.png image which under Assets folder, can the image display well?

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortunately - no. It makes toast not displaying at all.

Comment: Do you mean after you added the src, the toast can't display? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Yes and I have no errors nor warnings. I've edited my post adding example.

Comment: When you tried to load your xml file, you can use StorageFile Api to get it and then load its content(e.g. `StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///MyFile.xml")); toastXml.LoadXml(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file));`) In addition, I tested to send a toast, it can display well including image. The example you provided is not complete, so it's better to provide a simple complete sample for us to test.